# A problem related to Kelvin transform from Harmonic Function Theory

Tags: polynomials

[image]

The above picture is from Harmonic Function Theory written by Sheldon, Wade and Paul, I don’t understand why polynomials are locally dense in $C^2$-norm and how can we conclude from this point that the result holds for arbitrary $C^2$ functions. I need more hints.

Answer (score 0):

You did not post the background information that states the nature of the proposition to be proved, which apparently refers to an identity involving some function called $u$. I am guessing that the following comments might be relevant.

The Laplacian of a function at a point only depends on the partial derivatives of that function of order 2 at that point. Any smooth function can be approximated, to second order, by a Taylor polynomial. Thus both the original function and the Taylor polynomial  will yield the same value for their Laplacian.